# How do I make a textbox scale to fill the whole screen

Tags: html, css

I'm making a little site where you can make books, and I’m having problems with making a textbox. The problem is when you make the textbox with some settings to it…

```css
#text {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px #008f7e solid;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  font-size: 45%;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="27" cols="50" id="text"></textarea>
```

Notice how I added some preset rows and columns to this. I want it to fill the whole screen vertically but if I set the width to something my preset rows and columns disappear.
My expectation is that I don’t loose my rows and columns but fill the whole screen. It works perfectly when you're using a small screen (you can see a photo of it
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2ZdY.jpg)) but when I use a bigger screen it either shows up small or fills the rows and columns disappear (you can see right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bqax.jpg).) I've tried everything from changing the display to block to changing the size of the font to crying in the corner but nothing seems to work. Please help!

**Update**
I’m giving up on this project because I can’t find a fix for this. Thanks for trying.

Comment: which rows and columns are you talking about that would disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to resize attribute textarea?
I hope I understand what you want, this is my solution. Hope this helps!

```css
#text {
background-color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 4px #008f7e solid;
min-height: 60%;
margin: auto;
font-size: 45%;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="27" cols="50" id="text" value="">Notice how I added some preset rows and columns to this. I want it to fill the whole screen vertically but if i set the width to something my preset rows and columns disappear. My expectation is that I don’t loose my rows and columns but fils the whole screen.</textarea>
```

Comment: This does work but I lose my preset rows and columns still

Answer (score 0):

you can add `width` and `height` to styles.

```css
body,html{
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
#text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px #008f7e solid;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  font-size: 45%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but when I paste this in my code but I lose my preset rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

With `height: 100vh;` you can achieve this.

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px #008f7e solid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;  
  width: 100%;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text">some text</textarea>
```

Comment: This does scale the textbox but my rows and columns just go away